# How do I preprocess JSON data before loading into Spark dataframe

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to transform a large directory of JSON files into CSV files. However, before these JSON files can be turned into CSV, or Dataframe, friendly format, I need to transform them and clip them. This is the done by the `transform_json` function.

Below is a solution that works, but it feels silly and slow because of the back and fourth of the `json.loads`/`json.dumps`.

```
rdd = (spark_context.textFile('*.json')
        .map(json.loads)
        .flatMap(transform_json)
        .map(json.dumps))

(spark_session.read.json(rdd)
    .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("output_dir"))
```

I need to put them through the PySpark Dataframe because I don't know all of the columns beforehand, and Spark will handle that for me.

How do I improve this code?

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to merge schema? 
You can use Parquet and read this :
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#schema-merging